# What issues would hourly partitioning cause in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hive

We were told that a best practice is to partition our Hive tables by day instead of hour due to the memory cost of hourly partitioning on the namenode.  But would there be an issue with moving our largest tables (~40 TB per year) to hourly partitioning?

The way I understand it, each file on Hadoop requires the metadata for 6 objects to be stored in the namenode's memory (1 file + 1 block)*3replications.  A partition is just a directory, and so I think hourly partitioning would increase the # of objects per day from 1 to 24, or the cost of about 4 files (which seems pretty tiny considering the speed benefits of going to hourly).

Is my understanding correct?  Are there any major drawbacks that I'm missing?  I'd be looking to change the directory structure from /path/to/file/2015/08/13/datafrom20150813T*.txt to /path/to/file/2015/08/13/15/datafrom20150813T15.

Answer (score 1):

Going from day to hour implies an increase of number of objects tracked by namenode, in relation to these tables, by 24. If you have 1 million blocks now, you'll have 24 million blocks after the change. The NM must keep the list of all blocks in memory and is ~150 bytes per block, so you run against the physical limit of your NM RAM.

That being said: RAM is cheap. *If* you can prove that hourly partitioning improves perf, then go for it and make sure your NM can handle it.

Comment: Why would the # of objects increase by a multiple of 24?  The number of underlying files wouldn't change.  For example, if there were 240 total files in each daily directory ... now there would be 10 files in each of 24 hourly directories.  In your example, I would think the # of objects would grow by just 23, and not 23 million.

Comment: BTW, if is performance you're worried that first and foremost you should use an efficient storage format, ORC or Parquet